# Receiving bitcoin

Tags: transactions

As a first-timer I got a little confused and didn't verify the transaction. That was a couple of months ago and I don't know where the Bitcoin went. Is it possible that I could find the bitcoin after all this time or have I lost it and chalk it up to experience.
Thanks

Comment: If you have either the send or receive addresses, you could search the [blockchain](http://blockchain.info).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the wallet which contains the address that received the transaction everything is fine. All transactions are stored in the blockchain and cannot be undone. To verify that the address which received the money is yours you have a private key for this address which is stored in your wallet. So if you have the wallet which probably is stored in your bitcoin client you own this money.